# Could I have any issue using the @ (at sign) in a *n*x directory?

Tags: linux, naming-conventions

I'm developing a website, and want to create a directory after the user username, what is going to be the email address (so I don’t have to generate new ɪᴅs, etc)

I've made some tests and it seems to work fine. Also, I didn’t find any documentation against using the "@" in a directory, but could I find some problem in the future with this approach?

I mean, might some browser not be able to upload images from this directory, or some other problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no.. there should be no problems.. browsers are trying to read the file and they don't care that much about the title only file content... (header matters)

So.. there should be no problem...

Answer (score 2):

if you plan to run perl scripts (and possibly other languages) against those files you will need to remember to escape the @ sign. It's not a huge problem, but I personally would not do it.

More importantly if the path is visible to the browser you would be disclosing the user's email address to the whole world.

I would suggest using something like an MD5 hash of the user's email instead. It is (relatively) unique, and you can recalculate it very easily if you need to. Gravatar uses this approach for instance. See: http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/hash/

Comment: what issue does bash have with the `@`?

Comment: uhm, very few it appears, I got confused with something else :) I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

Historically some remote filesystems have used the `@` to "escape" from normal path processing to do "interesting" stuff.

Some version control systems use `@` to denote a certain version of a path (e.g. Subversion, ClearCase).

Some other tools use `@` to denote "user@remote_host" stuff - AFAIK `rsync` is one of them which might bite you - you should check if that tool is used somewhere on your site for backup or syncing or something like that.

So - *I* would not use that character within filenames.